# Remove Column Names in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new to R and am struggling to remove the column names for this graph. Here is a small sample of the 4417 row data which contains 3 trials and 8 tests. I have used row.names=FALSE, which doesn't remove their names from the graph.

```
Test    TestNumber  Display Trial   TrueValue   Subject Response
Vertical Distance, Aligned  1   1   B   0.6 1   0.6
Vertical Distance, Aligned  1   1   B   0.6 2   0.55
Vertical Distance, Aligned  1   1   B   0.6 3   0.7
Vertical Distance, Aligned  1   1   B   0.6 4   0.6
Vertical Distance, Aligned  1   1   B   0.6 5   0.65
Vertical Distance, Aligned  1   1   B   0.6 6   0.6
Vertical Distance, Aligned  1   1   B   0.6 7   0.5
Vertical Distance, Aligned  1   1   B   0.6 8   0.65
Vertical Distance, Aligned  1   1   B   0.6 9   0.5


ggplot(ds, aes(x=factor(Response),
y=TrueValue, 
row.names=FALSE, 
color=Trial,sd(x))) 
+ geom_boxplot(notch=FALSE) 
+ scale_y_continuous("Response") 
+ scale_x_discrete('Trial') 
+ theme_bw() 
+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0)) 
+ theme(text=element_text(size=10, family="Arial")) 
+ ggtitle('Trial Median Comparison \n to Look for Over Estimation')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean by "column names"? And more detail about what specifically you want to fix with the graph? I think maybe you're using some terms that mean something specific to us, but don't mean what you may think.

Comment: It would be good if you could also provide sample data and the plot for the sample data. Your data doesn't recreate the plot. Also, formatting it as runable code would be nice. I had to turn your pasted data into a data frame, and you could paste it as a data frame directly. See [reprex](https://github.com/jennybc/reprex) for making easy reproducible examples.

Comment: But, in lieu of that, you probably want something like this:

    labels = c(<list of labels for each trial>)
    scale_x_discrete('Trial', labels = labels)

Comment: Thank you for organizing my table into rows and columns. As you can see, I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow as well. @Joran, as you can see in the image the graph is showing all the names of the tests in the column. I'm basically trying to eliminate everything just above Trial and below the graph.

Comment: @Potterzon, unfortunately reprex isn't available for R version 3.2.2. I also tried labels=labels and it did not change anything.

Comment: So the only modification you're looking for is to simply _remove_ the x axis tick mark labels? If so, you'd want `theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())`. If that's not what you want, then I still don't understand your question.

Comment: @joran That is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank you for your assistance. I'm sure it was a elementary fix, but being new to R your assistance was greatly appreciated.